Overdetermined system of linear equations with one unknown
I have found a piece of software code that I am trying to understand. Apparently it is solving an overdetermined system of three linear equations with a single unknown. There is not much documentation to it, except for this: "We solve in a standard fashion in the least-squares sense for the desired parameter c."
Below is the system of equations with c being the unknown.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A-a\\B − b − d\\
C − ad
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\a\\b
\end{pmatrix}c$$
To me this appears to be a very simple example of an overdetermined system of equations. However, as a non-mathematician I am overwhelmed by the explanations and examples on the least squares method that I find online, which always have at least two unknown variables.
My questions are:

Is using the least squares method appropriate for approaching this overdetermined system of equations, or is there a better or more simple method in this case?
Is there an "entry level" resource that can help non-mathematicians (I am an engineer by education) understand how such a simple case is solved with the least squares method?

The source for the equations is eq. (5.12) in this paper about a quartic equation solver:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271196271_The_Low-Rank_LDLT_Quartic_Solver
The code is in the supplementary source code (LDLT quartic sub (subroutines)):
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271196182_LDLT_quartic_sub_subroutines

It is a matter of personal choice for your first question, however the least square method is commonly used since it derives from a scalar product. You should study linear algebra and normed vector spaces

The least squares method is the gold standard for many over-determined systems of equations, not necessarily linear. I doubt very much that any textbook would include the elementary treatment of the linear one variable case, so here it is for you:
Assume we have an over-determined system $a_1x=b_1,\dots, a_nx=b_n$ (say, $1x=2,2x=3,3x=4$). For every value of $x\in\mathbb R$ and every equation, we consider the "discrepancy" $D_j(x)=a_jx-b_j$ between the left and the right hand sides (say, if we take $x=5$ and the second equation $2x=3$, then the corresponding discrepancy is $D=2\cdot 5-3=7$).
The exact solution of the system would make all discrepancies vanish (i.e., all left hand sides will be equal to the corresponding right hand sides). Unfortunately, for the over-determined systems, to achieve this is often impossible: when we make one discrepancy $0$ (or just small), some other one becomes large. So we need to decide how to balance them. The least squares method calls for the minimization of the quantity $D_1(x)^2+\dots+D_n(x)^2$, which, in the case of the linear system we have, becomes
$$
(a_1x-b_1)^2+\dots+(a_nx-b_n)^2=Ax^2-2Bx+C
$$
where
$$
A=a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2\\
B=a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_n\\
C=b_1^2+\dots+b_n^2\,.
$$
In our numeric example, we have
$$
A=1^2+2^2+3^2=14, \\ B=1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4=20, \\
C=2^2+3^2+4^2=29.
$$
To minimize the quadratic polynomial $Ax^2-2Bx+C$, just write it in the form
$$
A(x-\tfrac B{A})^2+(C-\tfrac{B^2}{A})
$$
and notice that the second term has no $x$ in it anywhere and, since $A>0$, the first term is never negative and becomes $0$ for $x=\frac{B}{A}$, which is "the least squares solution" of the system. For our numerical example, we get $x=\frac{20}{14}=\frac{10}{7}$, yielding the discrepancies
$-\frac 47, -\frac 17, \frac 27$ in our three equations respectively. It is important to understand here that each individual discrepancy can be diminished, but only at the expense of increasing some other ones, so the sum of their squares will become larger if you deviate from the least squares solution in any direction.
This is how it works. There are many variations of the method (you can add the discrepancies with weights, consider the case when you have more than one variable, investigate non-linear systems, etc., etc.), but since you requested the very basics, I'll stop here. Hope it helps a bit :-)
